# How to use of list in LINQ with Contains or Exist or equal operator

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have used one list of EmployeeID and I want to find an employee from the employee table where employee id exists in the list of EmployeeID using LINQ.

I tried this query, but it gave me an error.

```
 objAbs.LstAbscon = (from p in db.Employees
    where p.Isdeleted != true && p.CNO == iCNO && p.EmpId.Equals(empIdLst.Any()) 
    where p.Isdeleted != true && p.CNO == iCNO && empIdLst.All(l => l.EmpId.Equals(p.EmpId))
    where p.Isdeleted != true && p.CNO == iCNO && empIdLst.Contains(p.EmpId)
    select new AbsconModel
    {
        EmpId = p.EmpId,
        PCODE = p.PCODE,
        PNAME = p.PNAME,
        Department = p.Dept,
        Designation = p.Desig,
    }).ToList();
```

In the query I have added three where clauses.

Please give suggestions to correct my query.

"empIdLst" is List of Employee IDs

Comment: Which error are you getting ? Especially on the third where clause which is the only that actually means something ?

Comment: If you came up with 3 different approaches why not try each one separately to see what the results are?

Comment: An easy way to break down your query is to read it backwards,`select`, `where`, `from`, `in`. If you do that it lessens the cognitive load, in my experience anyway. You have a lot of re-iterated code in this `where p.Isdeleted != true && p.CNO == ICNO` I would try to cut this down, in a larger query especially, duplicated queries will slow down the overall speed of your query.

Comment: i have use all three separately different ways not with all ....this is i have just add all way which i have test ....@juharr

Comment: @Vishnupatel Then what were the results of using each one and how do those results differ from what you expected?  As it stands I believe the third one is what you want, but if it was I don't know why you're asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ONLY this

```
p.Isdeleted != true  && p.CNO == iCNO && empIdLst.Contains( p.EmpId )
```

Answer (score -1):

`empIdLst.Any()` will return `true` or `false` depends whether it's empty or not.

Looks like you need the third one only :

```
    where p.Isdeleted != true && p.CNO == iCNO && empIdLst.Contains(p.EmpId)
```

What does it return with this condition?